# Parse.com findObjects() get data

Tags: ios, parse-platform, synchronous, pfquery

I need to run a SYNCHRONOUS call to parse.com. This is what I got:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"myClass")
    query.whereKey("groupClassId", equalTo:self.currentGroupId)
    query.selectKeys(["objectId", "firstName", "lastName"])
    self.arrayCurrentData = query.findObjects() as Array<myData>
```

This return the correct number of rows from parse.com and fills up my local array. But how can I extract the data from the array? If I look at the array at runtime it shows that all the data I need is in 'serverData' in self.arrayCurrentData.

Normally if I loop an async(findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock) filled array I would ask

```
self.arrayCurrentData[i].lastName
```

to get the lastName, but that is not the case in the sync array. There I can't ask directly for values (or so it seems).

Anyone who know what I am talking about and how to get data synchronous from parse.com?

Comment: Using `self.arrayCurrentData[i].lastName` should work in this case. Are you getting an error? Provide more information please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the PFObject's attributes with `valueForKey()`.  This is true whether or not the object was fetched synchronously.  In other words...

```
self.arrayCurrentData[i].valueForKey("lastName")
```

**EDIT** - This approach generates a compiler message because you've typed the response as `Array<myData>`.  But find returns PFObjects, so ...

```
self.arrayCurrentData = query.findObjects() as [PFObject]
```

... is the correct cast.  I'm not a swift speaker, but the expression `self.arrayCurrentData[i].lastName` pleases the compiler because `arrayCurrentData[i]` is typed as `myData`.  But this fails at run time because the real returned objects are PFObjects.

As an aside, I'd take a hard look at the rationale for fetching synchronously.  I can't think of a case where its a good idea on the main thread.  (off the main okay, but then you've already opted for asynch vs. the main, and the block-based methods provide a good way to encapsulate the post-fetch logic).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already tried that. The error when I try self.arrayCurrentData[i].valueForKey("lastName") is: 'Could not find member valueForKey'.

Comment: And his name was BINGO! Thanks very much for your help danh!